# Unique id from 2 values (Hi, Lo) & check if all data loaded into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

a.I am building a DW using SQL Server. What options do I have in order to create an ID from 2 int values (High and low) and how I may reference this unique value with the incoming value?
ex. Currently I have to check if 10 is between 9 and 11, in order to reference the range name of value 10.
b. I will update a table from three others daily. How I may check for any data loss? I am thinking about a compare with counting rownumbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `BETWEEN` or the `<` and `>` operators to check if a number is between a high and low value.

Comment: I thought about between but I believe it will be slow, that's why I am thinking a way to check it with one value and not two

Comment: BETWEEN isn't slow if your table is indexed for the query.   It's much better than any of the options involving only one number.